# How to select the option Books from the dropdown listbox within https://www.amazon.in/ using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, html-select, webdriverwait

How to select the option books from the dropdown listbox within https://www.amazon.in/ using Selenium in Python?

I am trying the code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchDropdownBox']").send_keys('Books')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('searchDropdownBox'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Books')
```

Answer (score 0):

The *drop down list* for the **categories** is within a `<select>` tag so ideally you need to use the *select* class inducing *WebDriverWait* for the desired element to be clickable and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='nav-search-label']")))
  mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='searchDropdownBox']"))
  mySelect.select_by_visible_text('Books')
  print((mySelect.first_selected_option).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Books
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: amazon_books]

Comment: sir plz help me.i am new to software testing

Comment: sir, the lines of code should be same. You just need to change the line while initializing the webdriver instance changing `driver = webdriver.Chrome(...)` to **`driver = webdriver.Firefox(...)`**.

Comment: File "C:\Users\chandru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view